# Replace some keys in json by jq

Tags: json, jq

I have json file like this one:

```
{
    "abc": "A",
    "abc-release": "B",
    "bcd":"C",
    "cde-release":"D",
    "cde":"E"
}
```

and would like to get resulting file like this:

```
{
    "abc": "B",
    "bcd":"C",
    "cde":"D"
}
```

That is:

1. remove all elements with key X if we also have key X-release;
2. rename elements with key X-release as X;

Need to make this work by using Linux commands like `jq` and `sed`. Preferably as one-liner with pipes.

I have spent multiple hours trying to implement this and best I could do is this jq command which returns array of keys which i need to delete.

```
jq "with_entries(select(.key|endswith(\"-release\"))) | keys | map(split(\"-\")[0])"

[
    "abc",
    "cde"
]
```

But how to feed this array in jq `del` method or some other way to get result what I need?

Second step (renaming elements) is easy. That can be done by jq but also can be done at the end simply by sed:

```
// simply like this
sed 's/-release//'
// or
sed 's/(.*)-release/$1/'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following constructive solution using jq has the advantage of being simple and efficient:

```
. as $in
| reduce (keys_unsorted[] | select(endswith("-release")|not)) as $k ({};
    . + {($k) : (($k + "-release") as $kr
                 | $in
                 | if has($kr) then .[$kr] else .[$k] end) } )
```